# Query about PostEevent in Ancestor from PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a query,

I have an ancestor window. In open event of ancestor window has one post event. That postevent will work in descendant window when we opens the descendant window?.

Please can anybody explain  on this.

Note: In descendant window open event has checked extended ancestor script.

Regards,
Ambat

Answer (score 0):

in PowerBuilder the events are called from the ancestor first. So let suppose you have w_grandfather => w_father => w_child, where w_grandfather is the base class (ancestor). First the w_grandfathers events will fire after that the w_father's eventes after that the w_child's.

If you uncheck the Extend ancestor script for example at w_father and you write there a script, than w_grandfathers event will NOT fire. First w_fathers event will fire and after that w_child's. In this case if you want to call w_grandfather's event you have to explicit write code like this:

super::event open()

Also notice, that when you use postevent your event will fire after the last event in the event list. If you need to "fire at will" :) you need to use trigger event.

I hope this helps. Feel free to ask! Have a nice day!

Br. Gábor

Answer (score 0):

Whether the method is an event or a function, and whether called directly or posted, PowerBuilder will first search for the method in the object that is instantiated, that is, the descendant. If a matching scripted method is found PowerBuilder executes it. If the method is not found, PowerBuilder will search up the chain of ancestors until it finds a matching scripted method. It's important to understand that the first scripted method found is what will be executed, and nothing else. PowerBuilder makes things confusing for events with their "Extend Ancestor" functionality. If you look at the exported syntax, you will see that if you leave this box checked, PowerBuilder inserts a call to the immediate ancestor at the beginning of the script using the `call` syntax. This is what DARKinVADER is referring to when he says events are called from the ancestor first. You should understand that this only happens because by default, each descendant script is calling its immediate ancestor. If you put a breakpoint in the grandfather's script, you will see all of the scripted descendant methods in the call stack.

Because PowerBuilder is inserting the call to the ancestor behind the scenes, many developers don't realize that when you extend an event, you become responsible for the `ancestorreturnvalue`. If you don't do anything with the `ancestorreturnvalue` it will be lost. You can break frameworks this way. For example, you can break the PFC Linkage Service by extending u_dw's events and not handling the `ancestorreturnvalue` correctly.